# getting form variables with JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have the following form(echoed through php), which when a radio button is selected, I want that value to be passed to a javascript function, which I can then deal with.

```
<form id=\"form1\" name=\"form1\" method=\"\" action=\"JavaScript:alterRecord()\">
<input name=\"radiobutton\" type=\"radio\" value=\"test1\" />Test 2<p>
<input name=\"radiobutton\" type=\"radio\" value=\"test2\" />Test 2<p>
<input name=\"radiobutton\" type=\"radio\" value=\"test3\" />Test 3<p>
<input name=\"radiobutton\" type=\"radio\" value=\"test4\" />Test 4
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"Submit\" />
</form>
```

And the JavaScript

```
function alterRecord(value) {
alert(value);
}
```

I can not find out how to get the javascript to obtain the form submitted value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something in Javascript on submit, but **not** have the normal POST or GET request occur (which causes the old page to unload and a new page to load), make sure to do something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body { background-color: black; color: white; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function handleClick(event)
      {
        if (console) console.info("handling click");  
        // for Firebug debugging, if you want it

    /* do something here */
        alert(this.textBox1.value);
        // I don't like alerts but it works everywhere

        if (console) console.info("handled click");  

        event.preventDefault(); // disable normal form submit behavior
        return false; // prevent further bubbling of event
      }
      function doit()
      {
        if (console) console.info("starting doit()");
        document.forms.myform.addEventListener("submit", handleClick, true);
        return true;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="doit()">
    <form name="myform">
      <div>
          <textarea name="textBox1" rows="10" cols="80">
'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.
         </textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The lines `event.preventDefault()` and `return false` are key. I also like using addEventListener rather than hard-coding an onSubmit in the form. Just a matter of style/preference I guess. (although addEventListener does allow you to have multiple handlers.)

Comment: This seems perfect. How would you modify this to work with onsubmit instead? However I call handleevent with onsubmit I cannot get it to register

Answer (score 4):

From the top of my head:

```
<form onSubmit="alterRecord">
  <input type="radio" id="radio1"/>
  ...
</form>

function alterRecord() {
  var radio1 = document.getElementById('radio1');
  alert(radio1.checked);
}
```

Comment: This will refresh the whole page, which I want to avoid.

Comment: You can stop the event propagation in the event handler. If you use a library like jQuery that can be as easy as adding "return false" at the end of handler.

Comment: i.e. jQuery('#my_form').submit(function(){ return false })

Comment: I use that a lot when showing HTML/CSS designs to a client, i.e. jQuery('A').click(function(){ return false });

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the javascript to fire when a radio button is clicked? Or when the form is submitted?

As mentioned, you can use onsubmit="alterRecord(this);"
Then you can use commands such as

```
alert(this.radio1.checked);
```

if you add id's to all the radio buttons as well..

And for the javascript to fire each time a radio button is clicked

```
<input type="radio" onclick="alterRecord(this);" ... />
```

Then the "this" command would allow you to access the radio button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The action attribute should point to a URL. If you want to do something in javascript when the user submits the form, use the onsubmit attribute. For instance, onsubmit="alert(42)".

If you call a javascript method from within the onsubmit attribute and pass it "this" as an argument, you'll have access to the form tag and all its childnodes and will be able to determine the current state of various controls at will.

Comment: I dont want to use a url, I want to use a javascript function

Comment: So just don't set the action attribute then. The attribute you want if you want to handle the form with javascript is onsubmit.

Answer (score 0):

First, start using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Now that you've got that going, [read the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) and it should be easy enough to do something like this:

```
$("input[name='radiobutton']").click(function() {
   // do stuff
});
```

Comment: jQuery's nice for some people but it's a whole other learning curve & you can do what the OP has asked without using jQuery and without doing anything fancy.

Comment: point taken, but it's still a valid solution to the problem.  I wasn't trying to evangelize