# Prevent HTML form submit from refreshing page and triggering another function instead

Tags: javascript, forms

How do I trigger a function while also preventing a HTML form from refreshing the page when a user hits the 'enter' key while an input element is selected?

==

I understand that `<form onsubmit="return false;">` will prevent the page from reloading. But how do I also get it to trigger another function, say `add();`...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683498/calling-javascript-from-a-html-form

Comment: is not a duplicate of that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,

```
<form onsubmit="your_function(); return false;">
```

Comment: Doh! It worked... I had the function after the 'return false;' bit earlier, I guess that was the problem?

Comment: yeah, simple mistake, glad it helped.!