# A form's "action" and "onsubmit": Which executes first?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

I'm trying to debug a webpage and I see a form element whose opening is

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="default.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm">
```

Having only a base knowledge of web `form`s, I'm wondering what the order of execution is for the `action` and `onsubmit`.

Comment: `javascript:` is useless in the onsubmit

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If `action` was resolved first, then the browser would leave the page, the JS execution environment would go away, and there would be nowhere to run the JS in `onsubmit`, so it isn't.

Event handlers run before default actions. They can cancel default actions.

Answer (score 20):

The `onsubmit` *must* execute first, as returning false from it stops the form being submitted, and thus the `action` ever being requested.

Answer (score 14):

This is explained in the HTML5 spec:

> [**4.10.22.3 Form submission algorithm**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-algorithm)
>
> When a [`form`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) element *form* is **submitted** from an element
>   *submitter* (typically a button), optionally with a *submitted from [`submit()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-submit) method* flag set, the user agent must run the
>   following steps:
>
> 1. Let *form document* be the *form*'s [`Document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document).
> 2. If *form document* has no associated [browsing context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsing-context) or its [active sandboxing flag set](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#active-sandboxing-flag-set) has its [sandboxed forms browsing
>      context flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#sandboxed-forms-browsing-context-flag) set, then abort these steps without doing anything.
> 3. Let *form browsing context* be the [browsing context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsing-context) of *form document*.
> 4. If the *submitted from [`submit()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-submit) method* flag is not set, and the *submitter* element's [no-validate state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fs-novalidate) is false, then
>      [interactively validate the constraints](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#interactively-validate-the-constraints) of *form* and examine the
>      result: if the result is negative (the constraint validation concluded
>      that there were invalid fields and probably informed the user of this)
>      then [fire a simple event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event) named `invalid` at the *form* element
>      and then abort these steps.
> 5. If the *submitted from [`submit()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-submit) method* flag is not set, then [fire a simple event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event) that bubbles and is cancelable named
>      `submit`, at *form*. If the event's default action is prevented (i.e.
>      if the event is canceled) then abort these steps. Otherwise, continue
>      (effectively the default action is to perform the submission).
> 6. Let *form data set* be the result of [constructing the form data set](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-the-form-data-set) for *form* in the context of *submitter*.
> 7. Let *action* be the *submitter* element's [action](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fs-action).
> 8. If *action* is the empty string, let *action* be [the document's address](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-document's-address) of the *form document*.
> 9. [Resolve](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#resolve-a-url) the URL *action*, relative to the *submitter* element. If this fails, abort these steps.
> 10. Let *action* be the resulting [absolute URL](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#absolute-url).
> 11. Let *action components* be the resulting [parsed URL](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#parsed-url).
> 12. Let *scheme* be the [scheme](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#concept-url-scheme) of the resulting [parsed URL](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#parsed-url).
> 13. Let *enctype* be the *submitter* element's [enctype](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fs-enctype).
> 14. Let *method* be the *submitter* element's [method](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fs-method).
> 15. Let *target* be the *submitter* element's [target](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fs-target).
> 16. If the user indicated a specific [browsing context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsing-context) to use when submitting the form, then let *target browsing context* be that
>       [browsing context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsing-context). Otherwise, apply [the rules for choosing a
>       browsing context given a browsing context name](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-rules-for-choosing-a-browsing-context-given-a-browsing-context-name) using *target* as
>       the name and *form browsing context* as the context in which the
>       algorithm is executed, and let *target browsing context* be the
>       resulting [browsing context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsing-context).
> 17. If *target browsing context* was created in the previous step, or, alternatively, if the *form document* has not yet [completely
>       loaded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#completely-loaded) and the *submitted from [`submit()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-submit) method* flag is
>       set, then let *replace* be true. Otherwise, let it be false.
> 18. Otherwise, select the appropriate row in the table below based on the value of *scheme* as given by the first cell of each row. Then,
>       select the appropriate cell on that row based on the value of *method*
>       as given in the first cell of each column. Then, jump to the steps
>       named in that cell and defined below the table.
>
>     ```
>                |        GET        |         POST
>     -------------------------------------------------------
>     http       | Mutate action URL | Submit as entity body
>     https      | Mutate action URL | Submit as entity body
>     ftp        | Get action URL    | Get action URL
>     javascript | Get action URL    | Get action URL
>     data       | Get action URL    | Post to data:
>     mailto     | Mail with headers | Mail as body
>     ```
>
>     If *scheme* is not one of those listed in this table, then the behavior is not defined by this specification. User agents should, in
>       the absence of another specification defining this, act in a manner
>       analogous to that defined in this specification for similar schemes.

Therefore, at step 5, the `submit` is fired, and can be canceled to prevent form submission. The action is resolved after that.

Answer (score -1):

`onsubmit` is executed first in order to check the format etc. Then `action` is executed to get/post the data to the backend.

Comment: If the form is valid and action is mentioned correctly then onsubmit never calls.