# Custom Validation in Contact Form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create some custom validation errors, but when I click on my button, it doesn't show the errors and sends the mail and it keeps showing the default html validation messages.

```js
   function validate {
     function email() {
       if (form.email.value == "") {
         alert("Ingresar un correo");
         form.email.focus();
         return false;
       }
       var re = /^[\w ]+$/;

       if (!re.test(form.email.value)) {
         alert("Formato de Correo invalido");
         form.email.focus();
         return false;
       }
       return true;
     }

     function name() {

       If(form.name.value == "") {
         alert("Ingrear un nombre");
         form.name.focus();
         return false;
       }
       return true;
     }

     function msg {
       if (form.message.value == "") {
         alert("Ingrese su consulta");
         form.message.focus();
         return false;
       }
       if (!re.test(form.message.value)) {
         alert("Error, ingresar solo caracteres alfanumericos");
         form.message.focus();
         return false;
       }

       return true;
     }
   }

   function validateEmail() {
     var emailID = document.form.email.value;
     atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
     dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
     if (atpos < 1 || (dotpos - atpos < 2)) {
       alert("Por faor ingresar un formato de email valido")
       document.form.email.focus();
       return false;
     }
     return (true);
   }
```

```html
<form id='contact-form' role="form" action="bat/MailHandler.php" method="POST">
  <div class="contact-form-loader"></div>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="grid_4">
        <label class="name">
          <input id="name" class="input" name="cf_name" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre" value="" required/>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="grid_4">
        <label class="phone">
          <input class="input" type="text" name="cf_phone" placeholder="Ingrese su Teléfono:" value="" />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="grid_4">
        <label class="email">
          <input id="email" class="input" name="cf_email" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su email" value="" required/>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <label class="message">
      <textarea id="message" class="input" name="cf_message" placeholder="Ingrese su mensaje:" required minlength="5" maxlength="999999"></textarea>
      <input class="primary-btn_2" id="btn-enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
      <a class="primary-btn_2" href="#" data-type="reset">Nuevo</a>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From where you calling `validate()`, `msg()` and other functions? And Oh, you don't have parentheses in some of your functions.

Comment: You have several syntax errors. `function msg`, `function validate` must have parenthesis....If you want to do currying, you might see [Nested functions in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3212519/2026740)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use onsubmit, fix syntax errors and invoke your validation functions

There are a couple of things you need to do.

1. Add an `onsubmit` attribute to your form. `onsubmit` will execute
   [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29014670/2757916) your form is submitted, so if there are errors in your
   validation, the form will not submit.

   `<form id='contact-form' onsumbit="your-form-validation-file.js" role="form" action="bat/MailHandler.php" method="POST">`
2. Fix syntax errors in your form validation file. From initial inspection, you're missing parentheses after function names `msg` and `validate`.

   ```
   function msg() { ... }
   function validate() { ... }
   ```

   You also have an `if` keyword which is incorrectly capitalized (see `name()`'s definition). After adding in the parentheses and uncapitalizing the keyword, your JavaScript shouldn't throw any more syntax errors.

   > Note: You may still have run-time errors--I have not vetted your
   >   actual logic.
3. In your form validation JavaScript file, actually invoke your functions. You define them, but never actually invoke them. You should probably invoke them in a separate if statement and return false if any of the validation fails.

   ```
   if (!validate() || !msg() || ....) {
       return false; 
   }
   ```

Doing the above should stop your form from being submitted and allow your validation to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working (kind of) but need to fix some minor stuff on my code.