# React: get formaction of button on submit

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to handle submitting a form in React. The form has two buttons which traditionally would send the form to two different locations using `formaction`. How can I get the `formaction` of the button the form is submitted in my `onSubmit` function in React?

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();   
    if (formaction === 'download') {
        ...
    } else if (formaction === 'stop') {
        ...
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            ...
            <Button formAction="download" type="submit">Download</Button>
            <Button formAction="stop" type="submit">Stop</Button>
        </Form>
    );
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the onSubmit method to the button instead of form.
And wire your name attribute to the `formAction` you like.
In that way, you could access the `formAction` in `e.target.name` inside the `onSubmit` method.

```
 onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();   
    const formAction = e.target.name
    if (formaction === 'download') {
    } else if (formaction === 'stop') {
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <form>
            <button name="download" type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Download</button>
            <button name="stop" type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Stop</button>
        </form>
    );
  }
```

Comment: This should be wrong as the form is not getting submitted so the other inputs are inaccessible. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You have assigned `onClick` handler to the `submit` buttons. How is form not getting submitted?

Comment: If there are other inputs in the form then they won't be accessible in the onSubmit function and also there are no state variables used as seen in the code.

Comment: What other inputs are you talking about? Why would other inputs needs the `onSubmit` function? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's break it down. You are trying to use a combination of **formAction** attribute and **onSubmit** function.

**FormAction** attribute is basically used to override the default **action** attribute of the form. It defines URL to hit when a particular **button** of type **submit** is pressed. Hence, the value of formAction should be a URL. Have a look here

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Again coming to **onSubmit** function. The event target of the **onSubmit** function is the **form element**, so you won't be able to get any attribute of the actual button clicked, as you want right now.

To resolve the problem you can either move the **onSubmit** function to the individual button and handle the server call manually.

Or, you can have two different URL's for buttons and handle the logic on the server.

Also, I would recommend reading the order of events while form submission.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29015329/2477472