# HTML form: action vs onsubmit

Tags: html, forms

As an HTML newbie I was doing some research on HTML forms in general, and action & onsubmit in particular, and Google gave me [the following hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014570/a-forms-action-and-onsubmit-which-executes-first#:%7E:text=onsubmit%20is%20executed%20first%20in,the%20data%20to%20the%20backend.&text=If%20the%20form%20is%20valid,correctly%20then%20onsubmit%20never%20calls.):

---

[image]

---

Naturally my first reaction was to take this at its face value but then upon clicking the link I discovered that this answer had been downvoted.  So obviously the first hit from Google is not accurate.

**Can we kindly have the correct answer to this question** so that hopefully it can be promoted to the top of any subsequent Google search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if I am not mistaken:

The **action** is an attribute that specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted. (aka what is the 2nd page that is supposed to receive the form-data once this form is submitted)

```
<form action="/somewhere.php">
 //Form Elements
</form>
```

The **onsubmit** attribute is used to specify which JS code to run.

```
<form onsubmit="someFunction()">
    //Form Elements
</form>
```

---

### ****To answer your question:**** onsubmit will always fire first.

Comment: The question was "Which executes first?"

Comment: @LeeTaylor fixed good catch.

Comment: it should ideally be `onsubmit="return someFunction()"`. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5196138/6908282